# Can't browse to EC2 LAMP instance. SSH is working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection

I can't figure out why I'm not able to browse to my EC2 instance. SSH is working, SFTP is working.

Those are my security rules:

```
HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule TCP 8080 0.0.0.0/0
SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0
d
HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0
```

It is running on an Ubuntu 14.04 x86.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you confirm your apache is working and listening to port 80?

Comment: apache is working, restarted as well. how do i make sure that it is listening to port 80?

Comment: Run this command netstat -anp | grep apache and see if it shows port 80 or paste the output here.

Comment: httpd started at port 80 but still no connection

Comment: Can you do a wget http://localhost call? ( or a call with the instance private IP)? This should verify it Apache is actually listening or not. Also check apache logs.